# Se pueden leer archivos .so?

Tags: java, android

He estado mirando los archivos de una aplicación y me he encontrado con un archivo ".so", al entrar en el me salen letras raras, hay forma de que salgan normal?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Vos podes leer cualquier archivo, siempre que sepas como esta codificado, encriptado, comprimido... no es algo magico... tenes que saber el como...

Comment: Hola Unknown, bienvenido, hay utlidades que abren estos archivos, generalmente te muestran el código en hexa, la pregunta del millón es: para que quieres abrirlo?.

Comment: obviamente si se pueden leer, pero como para que querrias leerlos? con normal te refieres a que lo represente como un dump hexadecimal?

Answer (score 0):

Los archivos **.so** son archivos binarios y contienen código nativo del procesador.

Existen muchos teléfonos con Android y procesadores también. Por lo tanto hay [varios conjuntos de instruccones](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis) y encontrarás carpetas con binarios específicos para cada uno.

---

De hecho, los archivos **.so** son las librerías dinámicas en todo sistema operativo Linux. La contraparte a las **.dll** en Windows.

Recordemos que [Android está basado en Linux](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform).

No hay forma de que un archivo binario *salga normal*. El único texto que puedes leer es el de los literales de cadenas.

Lo que sí puedes hacer es usar alguna herramienta como [`objdump`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objdump) para obtener el código ensamblador de la librería.